# How to update a java swing gui witha server from another thread?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, thread-synchronization

I have this Java Swing application that starts a new thread that uses a executor pool to open a socket server every time a incomming client tries to establish a connection.

The application need two buttons, one to start and another to stop the server. What I want is to show the server status, and disable the opposed button until its status changes.

This is what I have by now, but I don't know how could I communicate with the EDT when the thread stops. What I can do is just check the `isRunning()` method.

Would it be better to use a SwingWorker?

```
public class ServerManager implements Runnable {

    private Executor mExecutor          = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private ServerSocket mServerSocket  = null;
    private int mDefaultPort            = 43012;    
    private volatile boolean isRunning  = false;

    public ServerManager (int port){
        mDefaultPort = port;        
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {           
            mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(mDefaultPort);
            isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning){
                mExecutor.execute(new IncomingClientThread(mServerSocket.accept()));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(mServerSocket != null){
                stop();
                System.out.println("Server closed");
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        try {
            mServerSocket.close();
            isRunning = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public int getServerPort (){
        return mDefaultPort;
    }
}
```

And this is what I have in the GUI thread: I'm using just one button and changing its text everytime it's pressed, but if the server disconnects for some reason, the button stays the same.

```
connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(mServer.isStopped()){
                    new Thread (mServer).start();
                    connectButton.setText("Desconectar");
                    infoLabel.setText("Servidor online en IP: " + NetworkUtils.getLocalIpAddress()
                            + " puerto: " + mServer.getServerPort());
                    System.out.println(mServer.getIpAddress());
                }else{
                    mServer.stop();
                    connectButton.setText("Conectar");
                    infoLabel.setText("Offline");
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help is wellcome!
Thanks.

Comment: wow, my mistake I was changing parts of the code and didn't notice that thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to give it part of the functionality of a SwingWorker -- give it a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object, and allow your GUI to listen for and respond to state changes.

e.g.,

```
public class ServerManager implements Runnable {
  public static final String IS_RUNNING = "is running"; // for the Event's name
  private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propChngSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
  private volatile boolean isRunning  = false;
  // other variables

  // addPropertyChangeListener(...) {...} goes here
  // removePropertyChangeListener(...)  {...} goes here

  public void setIsRunning(boolean isRunning) {
    boolean newValue = isRunning;
    boolean oldValue = this.isRunning;
    this.isRunning = isRunning;
    propChngSupport.firePropertyChange(IS_RUNNING, oldValue, newValue);    
  }

  public void run() {
    // ....
  }

  // other methods
}
```

The key being to never change the isRunning property outside of its setter method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend. I'm a little fresh in event listeners so I had to take a deep look into it, but now I understand it.

Comment: ey @Hovercraft, I've moved all the listener stuff into a singleton enum to keep track of the server status and other listeners more I'll add, just to sepparate it from the network logic. Do you think that's okey?

Answer (score 0):

So, what I've done as was recommnded by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels was:

In the threaded class:

```
    public class ServerManager implements Runnable {

...     
        public static final String IS_RUNNING = "IS_RUNNING";

        private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pChange = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);


        public void setIsRunning (boolean isRunning){
            boolean newValue = isRunning;
            boolean oldValue = this.isRunning;
            this.isRunning = isRunning;
            pChange.firePropertyChange(IS_RUNNING, oldValue, newValue);         
        }   

        public void addPropertyChangeListener (PropertyChangeListener listener){
            pChange.addPropertyChangeListener(IS_RUNNING, listener);
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
            pChange.removePropertyChangeListener(IS_RUNNING, listener);
        }
...
    }
```

And in the GUI class:

```
public class StatusPane extends JPanel{

    private ServerManager mServer;

    public StatusPane() {       
    ...
        mServer = new ServerManager();

        mServer.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                System.out.println(evt.getPropertyName() + " cambia su valor de " 
                        + evt.getOldValue() + " a " + evt.getNewValue());
            }
        });
    ... 
    }
}
```